# Webpack can't resolve relative imports in package

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-4

I'm totally stumped. I have built a sass package and am trying to consume it via npm in another repo. When I import the sass package, at first I had failures because webpack couldn't resolve the node_module references in the imported package. Things like:

```js
//my-sass-package/index.scss
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/variables';
```

I added `includePaths` to my sass-loader and that resolved the original issue but now the relative paths to font files in the fontawesome package are failing to resolve.

So the chain of consumption is:

```js
my-consuming-repo < my-styles-package < fontawesome
```

And the failure occurs here:

```js
//fontawesome variables.scss
'../webfonts/*.woff
```

Here's my webpack config. Any help greatly appreciated!!

```js
module.exports = async ({ config }) => {


    config.module.rules = [...config.module.rules, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            { 
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sassOptions: {
                        includePaths: ['./node_modules']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff2'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
        }
    },
    // load these fonts normally, as files:
    {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    }]

    config.resolve = {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    }

    return config;
}
```

Exact error

```js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2' in 'my-styles-package\sass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the resolve-url-loader plugin for use with .scss files which seems to connect sass references to font files, hence the error about `.woff2` type files being missing.